# Подождать выполнение запроса sqlite на node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, sqlite3

Хочу чтобы результатом выполнения функции был массив массивов с объектами, которые получены из БД.

```
function cat () {
    var keyboard = []
    var res = []
    db.each('SELECT id, Name FROM Categories', (err, row) => {
        var obj = {}
        obj.text = row.Name
        obj.callback_data = row.id
        res.push(obj)
        keyboard.push(res)
        res = []
    })
    return keyboard
}
```

Но **db.each** работает асинхронно и результат выполнения функции пустой массив. Как подождать выполнение запроса?
То, что ожидаю от выполнения функции:

```
[
  [ { text: 'Кот 1', callback_data: 'cat_1' } ],
  [ { text: 'Кот 2', callback_data: 'cat_2' } ]
]
```

Comment: Посмотрите https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/

Comment: @vsemozhebuty благодарю!

Answer (score 1):

Вы должны сделать свою функцию асинхроной и работать с ней как с асинхронной функцией:

```
async function cat() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        db.all('SELECT id, Name FROM Categories', [], (err, rows) => {
            if (err) {
                return reject(err);
            }

            const arr = rows.reduce((acc, row) => {
                acc.push({
                    text: row.Name,
                    callback_data: row.id
                });
                return acc;
            }, []);

            resolve(arr);
        });
    });
}
```

Использование, вариант 1:

```
cat()
  .then((objects) => console.log(objects))
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

Использование, вариант 2:

```
(async () {

  try {
    const objects = await cat();
    console.log(objects);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }

})();
```

Comment: большое cпасибо!

Comment: @OleksandrShershak пожалуйста, пометьте ответ принятым, если он вам помог

Answer (score 0):

Используйте [better-sqlite3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/better-sqlite3). Он в десятки раз быстрее и там нет проблем с асинхронностью.

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/546983)

Comment: А что самое главное? Разобравшись изначально в инструментарии, у человека не было бы проблемы, с которой он столкнулся. Человек использует медленный не оптимизированный код с псевдо-асинхронностью вместо нормального легковесного доступа напрямую к библиотеке без лишних С++-абстракций. Чем платится отсутствием толковой документации, неудобным API и скоростью работы приложения.

Comment: зачем Вы мне это написали? Я не спорю, что предоставленная Вами информация может быть кому-то полезна. Я просто сомневаюсь, что данное сообщение может потянуть на полноценный, однозначный и объективный ответ. Это может быть неплохим советом. Но советы лучше оставлять в комментариях.

Comment: сообщение которое вы Выше пытались оспорить оставлено не мной лично, а роботом из очереди проверок. Учитывайте это в следующий раз, когда будете отвечать на подобные комментарии.